# How do I select a row in sqlite with a name on the row instead of an id with python?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, tkinter

I'm programming a store management system in python using sqlite as database. I want to be able to see Item price when the name of the item is entered instead of the Item id...below is the code snippet

```
   def ajax2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_name = self.entername_e.get()
        #get the products info with that name or id and fill labels above
        query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name=?"
        result = c.execute(query, (self.get_name, ))
        for self.r in result:
            self.get_name = self.r[1] #name
            self.get_price = self.r[4] #sp
            self.get_stock = self.r[2] #stock
        self.productname.configure(text="Product's Name: "+ str(self.get_name))
        self.pprice.configure(text="Price: Gh "+str(self.get_price))
```

Anytime I run the code after entering the name in the label Entry, the name appears even if it's not in the database and an error message follows in the command line like below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\GH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in 
__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "main.py", line 96, in ajax2
self.pprice.configure(text="Price: Gh "+str(self.get_price))
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'get_price'
PS C:\Users\GH\Desktop\Developments\Store Management Software>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is not present in the database, the cursor returned by the query is empty and the loop is not entered. As a result, `self.get_name` is unchanged and keeps the entered value, and `self.get_price` is not set, hence the error.

You shoud explicitely test for that case:

```
    ...
    result = c.execute(query, (self.get_name, ))
    empty = True
    for self.r in result:
        empty = False
        self.get_name = self.r[1] #name
        self.get_price = self.r[4] #sp
        self.get_stock = self.r[2] #stock
    if empty:    // name is not present in database
        ...
```

Comment: This works for me but how does the empty = True and the empty = False works to tests for that case

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you understand the object oriented approach in this python code. The *self* keyword is used to access the underlying object, of which all the attributes should be defined in the *init* function of the class. These attributes should only be there to represent the state of an instantation of the class. See this link : [link](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)

You should always be careful when altering objects by accessing the attributes directly. A common practice is to only access them by getters and setters, e.g.

```py
def getAttribute_1(self):
   return self.attribute_1
```

There are lots of good books and tutorials about object oriented programming available if you want to learn more about it, just google it.

In this case, for example, I don't see why you do:
`for self.r in result: ...`
when you should let go off the self keyword:
`for r in result: ...`
As this result variable is only relevant within the scope of your function.

Furthermore, if you want to set the price attribute of your current object, you should define that attribute in the **init** function:

```py
def __init__(self, ...)
    self.price = 0 """or whatever default value 
you want to give it, or initiate it by giving the initial 
value as an argument for the constructor"""
```

maybe define a getter and setter like this:

```py
def get_price(self):
    return self.price
def set_price(self, new_price):
    self.price = new_price
```

Then use these methods in your ajax function. Just remember to make a distinction between local variables, e.g. `price = result[4]` which are only relevant in this function, and attributes of your object, like `self.price`! These are 2 very different concepts.

To respond to your error in this example: the get_price is not set if the results returned by the query are None, in which case the loop will not be entered. In this case, the self.get_price attribute of you object has never been created, hence the error.

Hope this helps